# How to delete temporary image from internal storage

Tags: android

I had to pass a bitmap from one activity to another, but I was getting OutOfMemory error while passing the bitmap as byteStream in `intent.getParcelableExtra`, so I saved the image temporarily in internal storage, and retrieved it in my destination activity.

**Source Activity**

```
Bitmap btmp = //my bitmap here.

                String fileName = "tempfile_wip";

                try {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    btmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
                    FileOutputStream fo = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();

                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), apply_effects.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error 010", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

**Destination activity**

```
try {
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_effect);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(this.getApplicationContext().openFileInput("tempfile_wip"));
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
catch(Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Error 009 occurred.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Since I have loaded the image in destination activity's ImageView I no longer need the temp image file. How can I delete this file from internal storage? I only have the filename `tempfile_wip` and do not have the absolute path.

Comment: From where you get bitamp try get same from on another activity.

Comment: It's a bitmap created from scratch. Kind of like a photo collage app where the final image is the bitmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `File tmpBitmap = getFileStreamPath("tempfile_wip");` which returns the absolute path on the filesystem where a file created with `openFileOutput(String, int)` is stored, and use `tmpBitmap.delete()`